# Twilio CallSummaryResource, How to access the child properties of generic object?

Tags: vb.net, twilio

I'm attempting to access the child properties of Imports Twilio.Rest.Insights.V1.Call

The JSON returned from the API looks like this:

```
"connect_duration": 36,
"properties": {
    "last_sip_response_num": 200,
    "direction": "outbound_api",
    "disconnected_by": "callee",
    "pdd_ms": 1151
},
"call_type": "carrier",
```

However, the `CallSummaryResource.Fetch()` returns `.Properties` a generic object:

```
  [JsonProperty("properties")]
  public object Properties { get; private set; }
```

Is there a better way to access the child properties then trying to parse it?

```
Dim properties As JObject = JObject.Parse(call_Summary.Properties.ToString())
Dim disconnectedBy As String = properties("disconnected_by").ToString()
```